# Wifi trouble Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, dell

I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on a Dell XPS 8700. I had wifi upon fresh installation but it stopped working upon reboot. I do not have an option to select the wifi menu. If I force it to show up, it will tell me no wifi adapter found.

I've been through several driver-related fixes with no luck so far. At the moment, I do not even have a driver in use for my wifi card (BCM43142).

The card shows up when I run `lshw -C network`
Downloading the driver on a usb and then attempting to download on the machine was unsuccessful; it required dependencies. Attempting to install the dependencies was also unsuccessful.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like I'm making a silly mistake.

Edit 1:
`iwconfig` outputs as follows:
`lo      no wireless extensions`

Comment: Can you run `iwconfig` and add the output to your question? And try to execute `systemctl umask wpa_supplicant.service` and `systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service` and `systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: @CrazyTux I added the iwconfig output, and the three other commands resulted in no change.

Comment: Can't you get a temporary ethernet connection by ethernet or tethering? If so, the solution is one minute away.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the Secure Boot Options in your BIOS

If this does not fixes your issue then try using Ethernet or usb-tethering from any mobile device to connect to internet and try the following commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```